Official documentation of `figure` (and other basic commands)
For stuff like figure which - I believe - isn't defined in any package but is "just there" (tm), is there an official documentation for them?
Thanks!

It is not "just there". Environment figure is defined in the class. So see the documentation of the used class.

if you type h to any error message it will mention that the official latex documentation consists of the latex book by Leslie Lamport and the LaTeX companion by Frank Mittelbach et al

@cabohah: But where would I find the documentation of the used class?

This depends on the class you are using. Most classes and packages in TeX Live and MiKTeX have documentations, which are installed by default with the corresponding LaTeX package (but you can opt-out the documentation installation, which is IMHO not a good idea for beginners). As an alternative you can find the documentation also on CTAN or texdoc.net. For example for the often used KOMA-Script classes or memoir. For the standard classes, which are part of the LaTeX base, see David's comment.

@DavidCarlisle. If you write this as an answer I can accept it.

If you type h to any error message it will mention that the official latex documentation consists of the LaTeX book by Leslie Lamport and the LaTeX companion by Frank Mittelbach et al.
The typeset sources are also freely available (classes.pdf and source2e.pdf)

Thanks, @DavidCarlisle.

I usually use the unofficial reference manual covering LaTeX2ε for standard LaTeX commands, even if it's not the official documentation (as clearly stated in its name).
It can be found on CTAN as latex2e-help-texinfo.
